# Controlling <param> value with <button>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a way (if there is one) to change the value of the second `<param>` tag with a `<button>`

Code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="dp_flash" name="dp_flash" class="placeholder_class" data="tooafraidtotellwhatitis.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me!, what do you want to do exactly? do you want to use something like a regex to change a string? or you want to change an html tag in a page with JavaScript? or ... ;).

Comment: @shA.t The latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnaly I use ReactJs which makes all of this a whole lot simpler. But this is totally possible from html/css/js. What you are describing here is script handling using js. For this, I advise you to look into javascript (you can check out https://www.codecademy.com/learn/all , they got some pretty neat tutorials.

Normally what you want to do is going to be along the lines of :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Where `"myFunction"` is the action that will change the value of the  tag. You can then change the value of the `<param>` in different ways but here is one that looks good:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: i feel stupid now. i have actually taken lessons there but now they're poof.

Comment: No problem, we all ask stupid questions anyways =) Try to see if you can sort this problem out using the links I gave you, and if you still can't, let me know and I'll try to give you the code to it

Comment: Yes that is one way to do it:

    `<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Change value</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").value= "yourvalue";
     }
    </script>`

Comment: So, now the value is changing but the quality of the actual Flash object isn't.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but it sounds like you are trying to change two parameters dynamically. In that case, you may need to make the same sort of script for the second parameter you wish to change

Comment: Oh, I just did it with your help. It's now working, because I added a 'refresh' button for the actual object for the value change to take effect.

Comment: Perfect, glad I helped!